Solving equations involving complex conjugates
I am trying to solve a system of equations using the Sympy solve() method, and my equations involve complex conjugates of the variables. This results in solve() sometimes not finding a solution which I know should be there, and throwing errors at other times.
I think my issue comes down to the following situation.
from sympy import symbols, conjugate, solve, pprint
x = symbols('x')
x_conjugate = conjugate(x)

solution_1 = solve(x+x_conjugate,x)
pprint(solution_1)

solution_2 = solve(x-x_conjugate,x)
pprint(solution_2)

I am not exactly sure what I expect the format of the output to be for these, but certainly the equation x+conjugate(x)=0 has solutions (the whole i-axis in the complex plane), and the equation x-conjugate(x)=0 has the whole real line as solutions.
How can I use Sympy to solve equations like these, or systems that involve equations like these?
I see this question, which gives a wonky work-around, but this seems unsatisfactory somewhat impractical when dealing with the kinds of things I want to do.
How to solve complex equations in python?

I defined x as complex and proceeded as:
x = symbols('x', complex=True)
>>> solve((x-conjugate(x)).as_real_imag(),x)
[{x: re(x), im(x): 0}]

The as_real_imag() method splits the expression into real and imaginary portions which must both be zero. If you define a and b as real symbols and construct x = a+I*b you may have better luck with the "direct" solving approach:


Is there a MatrixSymbol version of this? I want to do something like x=(MatrixSymbol('x',2,2,complex=True)) so that I can solve matrix equations over complex numbers, but this does not seem to be supported as far as I can tell. I can also post a new question if that would be preferable.

I'm not sure about that.

You can express x in terms of its real and imaginary parts. I'll call it z and then z = x + I*y:
In [24]: x, y = symbols('x, y', real=True)

In [25]: z = symbols('z')

In [26]: ze = x + I*y

In [27]: eqs = [z - ze, ze + conjugate(ze)]

In [28]: eqs
Out[28]: [-x - ⅈ⋅y + z, 2⋅x]

In [29]: solve(eqs, [z, y, x])[z]
Out[29]: ⅈ⋅y

The answer z = I*y results from the system being underdetermined.
